# Llamar una función al presionar una tecla con Knockout JS

Tags: javascript, visual-studio, knockoutjs

Estoy tratando de hacer que un componente en mi proyecto de Visual Studio se cierre al presionar una tecla, en este caso la tecla ESC, para esto tengo mi función que cierra este componente a través de un link pero quiero que también use esa función cuando oprima la tecla ESC, cree mi funcion que valida si la tecla oprimida es el ESC y mande a llamar a la funcion de cerrar:

```
this.cerrar = function (e) {
            if (e.keyCode == 27) {   //27 es el keycode que corresponde a ESC
                CerrarCorreoComponente();  //funcion que cierra el componente
            }
        }.bind(this);
```

Y despues agrego las etiquetas div encerrando el componente al que quiero cerrar:

```
<div data-bind="event: { keypress: cerrar }">
          //componente
</div>
```

Al aplicar esto básicamente no hace nada, no llama la función al presionar la tecla ESC. Soy nuevo con KnockoutJS, se podría saber que es lo que me estaria fallando?

Comment: A veces el keypress no funciona muy bien en algunos navegadores, prueba a ponerle el evento keyup - Te dejo un enlace en inglés en el que le ocurre lo mismo que a ti https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1160008/which-keycode-for-escape-key-with-jquery

Comment: @RaúlMonge sigue sin funcionar con keyup pero estoy checando el link  que pusiste